# Good sites for descriptions/rules of different genres?

Tags: genre, resources, inspiration, rules

I just listenend to an episode of [Writing Excuses](http://www.writingexcuses.com/2009/07/) where they discussed genre blending. I found the topic very inspirational, but as one tend to only read books of certain genres, I was wondering if there are resources that gives good overview of "all" genres.

I consulted Captain Obvious on the matter, and he replied: "Read multiple books of each genre". Sound advice indeed, but then there is something called time.

I'm looking for a quick way to see the main ingredients, so I can deceide if the genre has elements that can work with my other ideas. If it has, I can start reading some books to pick up the nuances.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This sounds like a very scientific approach to something that's not a science. :-) In any case, [Wikipedia's article on Genre Fiction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genre_fiction) is probably as good a place to start as any.  From there, you can click on links for more detailed analyses of genres that look interesting to you.  That said, you're not actually going to be able to effectively mix genres until you've read a bit (or a lot) from each one.  It may take a lot of time, but, hey - nothing good in life ever comes easy. :-) Good writing takes years to develop, which also means years of reading.  It may take time, but so does mastering any other trade.  Get ready to put in your 2,000 hours - because that's what it'll take!